# Customer Login - form_key validation fails - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login, form-validation

Hi i am trying to login to the customer but it redirects to login page.

I checked in there is form_key validation in `LoginPost.php` it redirects to the same page. But the same thing is working on live site. How can i resolve it. Any help.

Comment: Check `var` folder has 777 permission or not. Try with `chmod 777 -R var` or `chmod 777 -R var/generation`

Comment: Check permission and cookie path